# Experimental evidence of Pauli principle for non-bound fermions

Tags: experimental-physics, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle

I mean electrons in atoms/molecules/solid bodies not count here.
I heared of an experiment measuring the degeneracy pressure of a fermion gas.

Comment: Measuring pressure of a fermion gas might well be an experiment in solids (more precisely - metals). In fact, this is a quantity often calculated in many-body solid state physics, which is known to be significnatly affected by the Pauli principle.

Comment: Perhaps Møller scattering is what you are looking for. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B8ller_scattering

Comment: My question is about free fermions. All of them are free.